# Unable to Set Value on Element in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriver

The Element is as follow:

```
<div class="sc-brqgnP gbUepm">
    <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="sc-cvbbAY jMSnje code ">5</div>
    <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="sc-cvbbAY jMSnje code ">5</div>
    <div class="sc-jWBwVP fyostQ"></div>
    <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="sc-cvbbAY jMSnje code ">5</div>
    <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="sc-cvbbAY jMSnje code ">5</div>
    <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="sc-cvbbAY jMSnje code ">5</div>
    <div class="sc-jWBwVP fyostQ"></div>
    <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="sc-cvbbAY jMSnje code ">5</div>
    <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="sc-cvbbAY jMSnje code ">5</div>
    <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="sc-cvbbAY jMSnje code ">5</div>
    <div role="button" tabindex="0" class="sc-cvbbAY jMSnje code ">5</div>
```

[image]

Now, I have tried Send keys and execute_script to set the value but I am unable to do so. I have used xpath with **role** and **class** attributes but none of it works.

```
self.wait.until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, locator)))
element = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, locator)
# self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value='123456789';", element)
element.send_keys('123456789')
```

I don't get any error, it just went without setting any value. The execute_script set the value within the div but didn't change the default value of 5 (which looks like placeholder value).

Appreciate if someone helps me out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to pass each individual keys for each location as they are all different div and hence have different *XPATH*.

Now, Ideally you would have looped through and passed each individual key (phone number) but as there is a *<div class="...>* in between, it will throw an error/exception.

Comment: It is not even setting one div value

Comment: Well, in that case I do need to see your whole website and code to check what is causing the issue.